# In browser XMPP OTR client

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I know [this list](https://xmpp.org/software/clients.html) exists, but Converse.js didn't seem to work with OTR like it claimed to, I couldn't get JSXC to work in browser, they seemed to be pushing downloads, and Salut a Toi wouldn't let me log in with an account from another server.

What I'm looking for is an in browser XMPP client that handles OTR properly and can chat encryptedly with Pidgin + OTR. Also I'm looking for something which does all the encryption client-side so the server it's hosted on can't read your conversations, it doesn't store your private key/fingerprint, you can read the JavaScript/client-side implementation so you can see what it's doing, and it works on mobile.

Clarification: The problem I had with Converse.js was I got "has requested an Off-the-Record private conversation <otr.cypherpunks.ca/>. However, you do not have a plugin to support that. See otr.cypherpunks.ca for more information." once, requesting from Pidgin+OTR, and also would also keep seeing "Exchanging private key with contact" forever but it never get done, so I don't think it's me, although I suppose it's possible I'm doing something wrong.